# Number of edges in a planar graph where every face has five sides

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

This was a practice question I saw.

I'm kinda confused about the part that says $5f = 2e$. Could someone explain that?

> **Question:** What is the number of edges in a planar graph where every face has five sides? (Answer in terms of $ v $, the number of vertices.)

> **Answer:** $ \frac { 5 ( v - 2 ) } 3 $. Eulers $ v + f = e + 2 $. $ 5 f = 2 e $ by counting edge face adjacencies. This implies $ v + \frac { 2 e } 5 = e + 2 $, which implies $ e = \frac { 5 ( v - 2 ) } 3 $. Notice this puts conditions on the values of $ v $ for which this can hold.

Comment: Double count the edges:

Comment: why do we double count them?

Comment: Each edge is adjacent to exactly $2$ faces. ... because the graph is planar.

Answer (score 1):

Double count the edges: Each face has $5$ edges ($5f$) & each edge is an edge of exactly two faces($2e$) (because the graph is planar.)